# How would one model this recursive relationship?

Tags: finance, mathematical-modeling

Given the hypothesis that share price isn't a direct function of value definition, creation, delivery, and sustainability. But instead, it's the recursive function of what "everyone else thinks about a company's value. And what everyone else thinks everyone else thinks about it.  And what everyone else thinks everyone else thinks everyone else thinks".

Any thoughts?
Moreover, how would you explain growth under this model?

Comment: Credit goes to @gidds

Comment: Down vote
Very intriguing question, possibly a theory if not yet exists could be developed arround it. Simple if the let's say sub-value stabilizes quickly, more interesting if oscilates or not converge. What would be a typical example of the second: any kind of virtual currencies. But in real world IMHO any information beyond 3rd step is irelevant.

Comment: Looks somewhat similar to [PageRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank)

Comment: Perhaps you should add a link to the comment by @gidds that inspired this question. "Yes, but the share price isn't a direct function of any of that; it's a function of what everyone else thinks about the company's value. And what everyone else thinks everyone else thinks about it. And what everyone else thinks everyone else thinks everyone else thinks…" https://money.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/281809

Comment: This sounds like a [Keynesian beauty contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keynesian_beauty_contest). Game theory may be relevant.

Comment: Do you know the concept "rational bubble"?